# Sharing hosted zone in different projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, domain-name, google-cloud-dns

I need suggestions for starting with Google cloud DNS for my projects.
I have 4 different projects named : `experiments`, `test`, `stage` and `prod`in GCP.
As of now `DNS` for all are hosted on `route53` as we were using `AWS` infra earlier.
Now, we have moved our infrastructure to `Google cloud` but `DNS` has not been migrated which I'm planning to move. I'm looking for suggestions to set up `peering` or `sharing` among projects in GCP

Currently, we have a single `hosted-zone` in `AWS` and all different project specific entries are the record-sets in the hosted zone.
For example, for `hosted-zone` "example.com", I have entries :
`expt.example.com` `stg.example.com` and `prd.example.com` as they all belong to same hosted zone and infra from individual projects call their respective entries.
Like this, there are multiple such hosted zone entries.
Other than this, there are some entries which should be accessible to all the projects.
Example: "common.example.com"

We are also going to setup DR projects for each which will have their own entries and shared entries across the organization.
Example, for `experiments` project in region  `R1` entry for `expt.example.com` should resolve to `R1` IP address and for Region `R2`, it should be the other IP address. But in case we have to fail over a specific portion of the application. We should be able to access other region's entries.

My initial thoughts are:

1. set the `hosted-zone` with the same name in each project and copy the respective entries for each project as record set in that.
   For common entries either I can create a new project and then do dns-peering with all these projects or put the common entries in public record which would be accessible to all these.
2. Or create a different `host-project` and then add all other projects as a `service-project` to it just and then let them access their respective entries just like going on in `aws`.

But I do not know how the case for DR should be handled and is there a better approach to do the above task ?
Any suggestion is appreciable. I'm beginner in setting up DNS so please pardon my mistakes.

Comment: 1) Your question is too broad and lacks one clearly specified problem with required details. 2) Google Cloud name resolution does not support peering with Route53. 3) You will need to setup split-horizon DNS. You mention that you are a beginner with DNS. Since you are planning to migrate to Google Cloud, then move/copy your DNS records and correctly setup Google Cloud DNS with private and public hosted zones. That is vastly easier than setting up custom name resolution.

Comment: 4) Instead of relying upon DNS name resolution, consider using a modern solution using Service Discovery. Products like HashiCorp Consul are very good at solving your type of problem.

Comment: HI John, thanks for responding .. 
I'm not trying to peer google cloud dns with route 53. 
All the projects are part of google cloud , so peering would be within GCP and within same organization too. I would see about other discover services options for non kubernetes instances

Comment: Your question is too broad and lacks one clearly specified problem with required details

Comment: HI John, I have added the information that the peering is required mainly in GCP projects. 
Not sure what else I can add to elaborate more about the requirements.
I'll keep adding more details, if I get to know what else could be relevant information
I hope that helps the readers ( eventually me )

Comment: Have you checked the documentation [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/)? It's more limited in compare to Route 53.

Comment: HI Serhii, Thanks for responding. 
Yeah, I have been reading this documentation too

Comment: I got to learn about creating DNS managed-zones and how to import export records in it, 
Also, I learned about creating peering among projects or hybrid infrastructure.